# "BEGIN blocks must have an action part" error in awk script

Tags: bash, awk

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=$(/usr/bin/find -name "INSTANCE-*.log")
echo "filename is " $filename

awk '
 BEGIN
 {   
   print "Processing file: " filename 
 }

 {
  if($0 ~ /Starting/) 
  { 
    print "The bill import has been Started on "$1 " " $2
  }

}'  $filename > report.txt
```

When I execute it I get the following error:

> BEGIN blocks must have an action part

My `BEGIN` block has a `print` statement so it has an action part. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happens because your opening curly brace is in the next line.

So what you need to do is to write `BEGIN { ...` like this:

```
BEGIN {
print "Processing file: " filename 
}
```

---

Note also that the main block can be rewritten to:

```
/Starting/ {print "The bill import has been Started on "$1 " " $2}
```

That is, `if ()` and `$0` are implicit so they can be skipped.